# Xamarin Android get item controls

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

In short: 
I would like to iterate controls with foreach.

In c#:

```
foreach ( TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) 
{

}
```

I just want the same with xamarin.android.
Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you need to get the View of the Layout where your controls are. Then, just loop through them.

```
  var viewGroup = (ViewGroup)FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.MyLayout);

        for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var childView = viewGroup.GetChildAt(i);

            if (childView is TextView)
            {
                //do what ever you have to do
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have Views and ViewGroups, so recursively iterate all the ViewGroups obtain all the Views

```
void IterateViews(ViewGroup vg)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vg.ChildCount; i++)
    {
        var view = vg.GetChildAt(i);
        if (view is ViewGroup)
        {
            IterateViews(view as ViewGroup);
        }

        Log.Debug("SO", $"{view.Id.ToString()} : { (view.Id != -0x1 ? Resources.GetResourceEntryName(view.Id) : "")}");
    }
}
var aViewGroup = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);
IterateViews(aViewGroup);
```